# How to remove a page from the Google search results

Tags: seo, sitemap, search-engine-indexing, google-index

Google says one can use the following method to remove a page from the search results:
by putting `-http://www.example.com/outdated.html` into the sitemap.
But what if the site does not exist anymore.

Comment: Where did you hear that you can put a minus sign in front of a in the sitemap to remove it from Google's index?   I've never heard that before and I can't find any references for it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes that link have nothing to see. But you can use following if you want to remove page from google search :

[Remove page URL from google](http://www.edicy.com/blog/how-to-remove-your-website-or-web-page-from-google)

Answer (score 0):

If the site doesn't exist anymore, you won't be able to host the sitemap file and share it with Google.

The site and all its pages will automatically get de-indexed in some time.